# What is the algorithm used in Integer multiplication?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, integer, multiplication

What is the algorithm used in `Integer` multiplication?

Is it a fast algorithm like Schönhage-Strassen algorithm?

Comment: I don't know the algorithm, but I did find [the source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/integer-gmp-1.0.2.0/docs/src/GHC.Integer.Type.html#timesInteger), which might be relevant.

Comment: In Haskell, for arbitrary precision arithmetic  GMP library is used. https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/commentary/libraries/integer. In GMP library, there are few algorithms used for multiplication https://gmplib.org/manual/Multiplication-Algorithms.html.

Comment: I doubt the Haskell standard defines this at all – for all it cares about, `Integer` could be implemented with Peano naturals and iterated addition. As for GHC – like keep_learning says, it doesn't try to be clever with this either but just invokes the GMP library.

Comment: GMP appears to use Schönhage-Strassen, but not until you start dealing with numbers with 10s of thousands of decimal digits.

Comment: There's some licensing issues with libgmp, you can google it but occasionally integer-simple is used instead or you can also look at integer-openssl